# How to show that $\frac{1}{V}\int_MR \, dV\ge\mathcal{F(g_{ij},f)}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

When I read the proof of Corollary 1.5.5 of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947) (204th page),I get stuck in the red box in picture below.How to show it ?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have recently asked questions from page 200, 201 (two), 203 (two), and now 204 of this paper. Are you sure you are putting enough thoughts on your own in reading it?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Maybe , I should work harder,thanks your  remind.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi   You are right. Although  it seemly waste much time ,but I am very happy when I find a answer. But I still not sure with it, I have written it in below .Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether I am right.

Let $f=k$,$k$ is constant. Because $\int_Me^{-f}dV=1$ ,
 then $1=\int_Me^{-k}dV=e^{-k}\int_MdV=e^{-k}V$. So,$e^{-k}=\frac{1}{V}$.

So, $\int_M(R+|\nabla f|^2)e^{-k}dV=\frac{1}{V}\int_MRdV$.

So,$\frac{1}{V}\int_MRdV\ge\lambda(g_{ij}(t))$

Because the $f$ is continuous about $t$ , So ,when $t\rightarrow t_0$, we still have the red box.Because the $\lambda(g_{ij}(t_0))\le0$,then $-\int_M(R+|\Delta f|^2)e^{-f}dv\ge 0$. So we can get the last inequality.

For proving $\lambda(g_{ij}(t_0)) \ge \int_M (R + |\nabla f|^2)e^{-f} dV$.Under **coupled flow** of 201 page,we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_M(R+|\nabla f |^2)e^{-f}dV=2\int_M|R_{ij}+\nabla_i\nabla_jf|^2e^{-f}dV\ge 0
$$
So, we have $\lambda(g_{ij}(t_0)) \ge \int_M (R(t) + |\nabla f(t)|^2)e^{-f(t)} dV_t$ ,when $t\le t_0$.

Comment: Your argument is largely correct, except that the calculation is really done at $t = t_0$ only. Indeed for $t< t_0$, it seems that $f$ might not minimize $\mathcal F(g_{ij}, f)$.

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, you are right. But the proof in 204 page do not need $f$ is minimize of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Indeed it does. you have shown $\frac 1V \int_M R dV \ge \lambda(g_{ij}(t_0))$. You need $\lambda(g_{ij}(t_0)) = \int_M (R + |\nabla f|^2)e^{-f} dV$ in order that you get the desire inequality. (This $f$ is fixed)

Comment: @JohnMa  I think $\lambda(g_{ij}(t_0)) \ne \int_M (R + |\nabla f|^2)e^{-f} dV$. I think just using the continue of $f(t)$, so, when $t\rightarrow t_0$, we have $f\rightarrow f_0$.So this inequality is right when $t\rightarrow t_0$.

Comment: It said "let $f_0$ be a minimizer of $\lambda (g_{ij}(t))$ at $t_0$. Note that $f\to f_0$ is not enough.

Comment: @JohnMa  Seemly, you are right. Let me think how to prove $\lambda(g_{ij}(t_0)) = \int_M (R + |\nabla f|^2)e^{-f} dV$ or  $\frac 1V \int_M R dV > \lambda(g_{ij}(t_0))$.

Comment: @JohnMa I add my proof to the answer ,is it right ?